# How to check which <option> is actually clicked?

Tags: jquery, select

```js
$('select').bind('click contextmenu',function(ev){    
})
```

`ev.target` is always a `select`,not `option`.

How can I know which one is now being clicked?

I can't do this:

```js
$('option').bind('click contextmenu',function(ev){    
})
```

Because it's not supported in IE8,and you can test it yourself!

It should also support right click, which fires the `contextmenu` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change event for the select box and can find the currently selected item using the following.

```
$("#sel").change ( function() {
    alert ( $(this).find("option:selected").val() );
});
```

Comment: @ unknown (google)  I don't see where in your question you said "right click"

Answer (score 1):

`<option>` cannot catch events in IE. It has no independent life of its own; select boxes are single indivisible OS widgets in IE so a click on an option will always instead generate a click event for the `<select>` element.

Whilst you might theoretically guess which option was being clicked from the `event.clientY` property, that would require you to know exactly how IE had rendered the menu, including what fonts were in use (somewhat within your control), and whether the pop-up menu had popped up downwards or upwards or hit the edge of the screen so misaligned against the select element (not within your control at all). For a very short menu you could hope that it'll always open downwards and calculate from there, but it's not really reliable. It's almost always best to let the click go through and just see which option is selected afterwards.

As for `oncontextmenu`, forget it. Right-clicking an `<option>` in IE does nothing, no event is generated for you to catch at all. If you want right-clickable menus you will have to replace your `<select>` with a JavaScript div-based pop-up analogue.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a solution might be to check the new `value` of the `select` : it should be the one coming from the `option` your user just clicked on.

Or you might also check the `selectedIndex` property of your `select` : it should also point to the `option` that's just been choosen.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the val()-method on the select element:

```
$('select').bind('click contextmenu',function(ev){
    var value = $(this).val();
})
```

OR:

```
$('select').change(function(ev){
    var value = $(this).val();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the jquery documentation as an example

```
 $("select").change(function () { 
          var str = ""; 
          $("select option:selected").each(function () { 
                str += $(this).text() + " "; 
              }); 
          $("div").text(str); 
        }) 
        .trigger('change');
```

From [Selectors/selected](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/selected)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the selected attribute. Something like this:

```
$("#YourSelect option:selected");
```